# Xcode 8 can't open Model.xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, xcode8

I am running macOS Sierra (Build 16A320), using Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) and have migrated all my code to Swift 3.

I can't open my `Model.xcdatamodeld` file anymore. Selecting it in the project navigator does not open up the "Core Data Model editor" view (not sure what it is called). I have tried restarting Xcode, but it does not work. I have tried deleting derived data, cleaning, does not work. I have tried double clicking, does not work.

`Model.xcdatamodeld` is visible in the Project navigator view, but it is not **possible to interact with it** (other than right clicking), **nothing happens when I click or double click on it**.

**EDIT: Problem solved, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626959/1311272)**

Comment: What does happen when you click on it?

Comment: Neither clicking, nor double clicking helped... But I solved it, check my answer :)

Comment: Glad you solved it, but for people searching in the future it might help if you described *what actually happened* when you clicked on it, instead of just saying that the editor didn't open. What did you actually see in Xcode when you tried?

Comment: Nothing... the `Model.xcdatamodeld` file was visible in the project navigator, but was not clickable. I will update the question to make this more clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so I solved it... Hmm not sure why but seems like some part of the Swift Migration guide messed up the Model.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Remove the model from the project (was not even asked about trash or
   reference, but delete reference if asked of course).
2. Re-add the file

This resulted in this Git change (screenshot from SourceTree):

[image]

As you can see, the `Model.xcdatamodel` (note difference vs `Model.xcdatamodeld`) file was missing! I guess it somehow got messed up during the -> Swift 3 migration?

Anyway, now it works! :)