# Can't open Data Model File in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode8, xcdatamodel

Using MacOS Sierra(10.12.1 (16B2555)) and Xcode 8.1(8B62). Created a new Project without selecting "Use Core Data". Now when I create a new Data Model, I can't open it in Xcode editor.

[image: screenshot]

Even if I right click, `Open As->` doesn't show any option.

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39626706/3207014), but the answer doesn't help me.

I have deleted and re-added file, even re-generated the data model. 
I have cleaned project and build folder.
Also committed to source control and then retried.
Even restarted Xcode and Mac, but nothing seems to be working.

How can I use Core Data in my project now?

Comment: This works perfectly in my setup with Xcode 8.1 (8B62). How are you adding the file?

Comment: New->File->Core Data Model, Its working fine for other projects of mine too.

Comment: Strange, in my Xcode version it says "Data Model" not "Core Data Model".

Comment: It says "Data Model" in mine too, I just wanted to point out its in section "Core Data".

Comment: Here is another idea. Maybe one of your other files or frameworks uses something called "User"? Could you try with a different model name?

Comment: Renamed the Model, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You could try open the package contents of xcdatamodeld, drag out the file inside with the same name and use it instead. I had the same problem and thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638028/5806210) solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I created the same file in a different folder to test if it will work and it did. I deleted it and tried to re create it in the folder i wanted then it worked